# My paired vectors are not getting sorted in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std, std-pair

I have made paired vectors and I want to sort one vector according to the values of other vector, but when I run my program the vectors aren't getting sorted. They just remain the same. And I think it is because of the pair that I have made I have actually just copied the code to perform paired sorts from internet and replaced the arrays with vectors.

```
// Sort an array according to other using pair in STL.

// Function to sort vector b according to the order defined by vector a

void pairsort(vector<int> a, vector<int> b, int n)
{    
    pair<int, int> pairt[n];

// Storing the respective array

// elements in pairs.

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

    {
        pairt[i].first = a[i];

        pairt[i].second = b[i];
    }

// Sorting the pair array.

sort(pairt, pairt + n);

// Modifying original arrays

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

{
    a[i] = pairt[i].first;

    b[i] = pairt[i].second;
}
}

// Driver function

int main()
{

vector<int> a{60, 100, 120};
vector<int> c{3, 2, 4};


int n = sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]);
pairsort(c, a, n);
}
```

Comment: `pair<int, int> pairt[n];` is not C++.  It may be a language extension provided by your compiler.

Comment: The definition `pair<int, int> pairt[n];` is a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and C++ doesn't actually have those. Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Copies* of the original vectors are passed to the arguments `vector<int> a` and `vector<int> b`. Modifying the copies will not affect what are passed in caller.

Add `&` after the types to make them references to reflect changes in the function to the caller.

Also Variable-Length Array like `pair<int, int> pairt[n];` is not in the standard C++. You should use `std::vector<pair<int, int> > pairt(n);` instead.

```
void pairsort(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b, int n) // make a and be references
{    
    std::vector<pair<int, int> > pairt(n); // use std::vector instead of non-standard VLA
```

After making this change, this usage of `sort` is wrong with `std::vector`:

```
sort(pairt, pairt + n);
```

It should be:

```
sort(pairt.begin(), pairt.end());
```

One more point is that `sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0])` in the `main()` function is not a correct way to retrieve the number of elements in the vector. It should be replaced with [`c.size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size).

Comment: Thanks alot, I really didn't had any idea that we need to add '&' after the type

Comment: But one last question , How can i sort my paired vector in descending order?

Comment: `sort(pairt.rbegin(), pairt.rend());` `rbegin()` and `rend()` takes *reverse iterators*, which refer the vector in the reversed order.